# AWS: This policy contains the following JSON error: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 228

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to add a policy to a AWS user using the create policy tool.  I have copied a policy from this AWS tutorial and pasted it into the policy creator tool, so presumably it should be valid JSON.  However, when I try to submit it says "This policy contains the following JSON error: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 228"

Two questions:

1) How can I fix this?
2) what does position 228 refer to?

[image]

Comment: You have missed closing Square bracket for Statement before Last Curly brace.

Comment: looks like the AWS docs have examples with invalid JSON :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a square bracket to line 10 after the curly bracket. I think position 228 refers to the 228th character.